# при запуске segmentation fault

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

````
void fillingArray(char** array);
void show(char** array);

int main ()
{
    char** table[25][80];
    fillingArray(&table);
    show(&table);
}

void fillingArray(char** table)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 80; j++)
        {
            table[i][j] = "0";
        }
    }
}

void show(char** table)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 80; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", table[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}```
````

Comment: Что у вас не так? Объясните подробнее.

Comment: Что должен делать код? Также приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: @Глеб из терминала запускаю программу выдает segmentation fault

Comment: @Глеб программа должна вывести пряямоугнольник из 0

Comment: Для начала разберитесь с предупреждениями компилятора. Используйте флаги `-Werror` или `/Wx` чтобы он не делал исполняемый файл при наличии предупреждений. Ну опции по предупреждениями тоже подкрутите построже.

Comment: Так и напоминает, как в слове из 3 букв сделать 4 ошибки... Неправильная передача параметров в функции (несоответствие типов), неверное (по типам же) присваивание `table[i][j] = "0"`, я бы еще сказал, что выход за границы массива (`int i = 0; i <= 25;` — это сколько элементов? Вы думаете, 25?), если бы вы в функции передавали массив...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, что вы хотели *написать*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fillingArray(char table[][80]);
void show(char table[][80]);

int main ()
{
    char table[25][80];
    fillingArray(table);
    show(table);
}

void fillingArray(char table[][80])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 80; j++)
        {
            table[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
}

void show(char table[][80])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 80; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", table[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Только вот если ваша консоль имеет размер ровно 25х80, то после последнего 0 в строке будет переход на новую строку, и `\n` сделает пустую строчку. Так что заполненный нулями экран вы так не получите.